# Trigger a function in already mounted Vue component from router-link in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a tricky communication issue between a `router-link` in my parent Vue component and a child component.

I would like to clear an input field on the child component, which is the main Index for my app. This component loads by default.

The parent App component contains the main navigation which contains a `router-link` routed back to the index like so:

```
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Index',  query: { search: '' }}" class="nav-link">                  
    Index     
  </router-link>
```

The Index component contains a search input to filter the index items list. The search value is tracked by the component's data.

```
 data() {
   return {
      items: [],
      tags: [],
      search:'',  
 }
```

The issue is I cannot seem to clear the search input when the `router-link` for the Index is clicked. I assume because the Index is already mounted clicking the link cannot trigger any function in the component.

I have tried using `$emit` by wrapping the link text in `<span @click="clearSearch()">`, putting the `$emit` in the clearSearch function and picking it up in the Index, but this apparently doesn't work from parent to child??

As you can see in the `router-link` above I have also tried passing as query like `query: { search: '' }` and adding the following to the main.js route configuration.

```
props(route) {
  return { search: route.query.search }
}
```

This sends the empty string in URL but I still cannot pick it up in the Index component to clear the search input, again I think because it is already mounted.

This seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but I am a bit stumped on it and don't know what else to try. I am still learning Vue so there might be something obvious I am missing. If anyone can help me out on how to achieve this I would much appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An easy hack would be to use `router.push()` in a method instead of `<router-link>` and to make `search` a prop and clear it from the parent.

This way you can store `search` in the parent data and clear it on click.

```js
// Parent component
<template>
  <div @click="navigate" class="nav-link">
    Index
  </div>
  ...
  <Index :search="search" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    navigate() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Index' });
      this.search = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// Child component
<template>
  {{ search }}
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      search: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```